# com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: remote_app_id does not match stored id with Facebook SDK 3.5

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to make use of Facebook SDK 3.5 to authenticate users for my android applicaiton following the link, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/. I am able to login to my application using facebook credentials from my emulator, using both facebook native app and facebook webpage(when facebook native app is not preinstalled). The issue is, for other user's emulator, only facebook authentication using webpage works but using facebook native app authentication does not work and the log says, com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: remote_app_id does not match stored id. I have verified the app_id, hashkey are consistent and as expected. Any thought ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If other people are compiling your code, they're most likely using their own keystore, which would result in a different key hash.

You can either use the same steps, and add their key hashes to your app settings, or you can distribute your debug keystore to the other users who will be compiling your app, or you can build your app as an apk using your keystore, and distribute the apk to the other users.

Comment: Good point. But I am not sharing the code. I have shared them the apk signed with release key.

Comment: The release key also generates a different key hash (the doc from developers.facebook uses the debug key). Did you add the release key hash to your app as well (the key hash field in app settings takes a list)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I had added release keyhash also in the list. The issue however is solved now. For some reason the release keyhash that i was generating using keytool and was signing the application was not what i was expecting. Found this while displaying the key used to sign application at run time, added this key to the list and the issue solved. Question is how the key is different from what i had generated using keytool and was signing the application.

Comment: have you solved this? i am encountering this one.. my generated hash key is different from the one that i log i tried putting the generated one and the one that is on the log.. however im still getting the remote_app_id does not match stored app id.

Comment: Yes. Are you testing the application in emulator? if yes then, the debug kye used to sign app will be different for different machines. You need to find the keyhash for other machines also and configure them in FB developer console. FB developer console allows you to put multiple keys.